# Access Sharepoint Document Library through Sharepoint Web Services

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint

Does anyone have code on how to access sharepoint document library through Sharepoint Web Services in .Net

Code is available if you do google search but none of them is working.

This is the code I'm trying

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Xml;
using Microsoft.SharePoint;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Services;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;


namespace WindowsFormsApplication2
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            XmlDocument xmldoc = new System.Xml.XmlDocument();

            string URL = "";

            string FileName = "";

            DownloadListItems.Lists objLists = new EncryptAndDecrypt.DownloadListItems.Lists();

            objLists.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;

            objLists.Url = "{siteurl}/_vti_bin/lists.asmx";

            XmlDocument xmlDoc = new System.Xml.XmlDocument();

            XmlNode xmlQuery = xmlDoc.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element, "Query", "");

            XmlNode xmlViewFields = xmlDoc.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element, "ViewFields", "");

            XmlNode xmlQueryOptions = xmlDoc.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element, "QueryOptions", "");

            xmlQueryOptions.InnerXml = "<ViewAttributes Scope='RecursiveAll' IncludeRootFolder='True' />";

            xmlViewFields.InnerXml = "";

            xmlQuery.InnerXml = "";

            try
            {

                XmlNode xmlListItems = objLists.GetListItems("Shared Documents", null, xmlQuery, xmlViewFields, null, xmlQueryOptions, null); //change the document library name to your document library

                XmlNodeList oNodes = xmlListItems.ChildNodes;

                foreach (XmlNode node in oNodes)
                {
                    XmlNodeReader Reader = new XmlNodeReader(node);

                    while (Reader.Read())
                    {
                        if (Reader["ows_EncodedAbsUrl"] != null && Reader["ows_LinkFilename"] != null)
                        {
                            URL = Reader["ows_EncodedAbsUrl"].ToString();

                            FileName = Reader["ows_LinkFilename"].ToString();

                            CopyAndSaveAttachment(URL, FileName);
                        }

                    }

                }

                Console.ReadLine();
            }

            catch (System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }

        }

        public static void CopyAndSaveAttachment(string URL, string FileName)
        {

            HttpWebRequest request;

            HttpWebResponse response = null;

            try
            {

                request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(URL);

                request.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;

                request.Timeout = 10000;

                request.AllowWriteStreamBuffering = false;

                response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

                Stream s = response.GetResponseStream();

                //Write to disk

                FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"C:\DownLoads\" + FileName, FileMode.Create);

                byte[] read = new byte[4096];

                int count = s.Read(read, 0, read.Length);

                while (count > 0)
                {

                    fs.Write(read, 0, count);

                    count = s.Read(read, 0, read.Length);

                }

                //Close everything

                fs.Close();

                s.Close();

                response.Close();

            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;

            }

        }
    }
}
```

Error which I'm getting is:
Error   1   The type or namespace name 'DownloadListItems' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) c:\users\fox7lsh\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\WindowsFormsApplication2\WindowsFormsApplication2\Form1.cs   36  13  WindowsFormsApplication2

Regards

Comment: Why do all the codes you find does not work? Any error messages? What did you tried so far? Which SharePoint version do you use?

Comment: http://www.sharepointkings.com/2010/05/download-attachments-from-list-item.html - Error which I'm getting is on - DownloadListItems.Lists objLists = new EncryptAndDecrypt.DownloadListItems.Lists(); - It says doesn't fine DownloadListItems - name space cannot be found. I don't know what I need to import to make it work.

Comment: http://sqlblogcasts.com/blogs/drjohn/archive/2007/11/02/Getting-a-list-of-files-from-a-moss-document-library-using-a-SharePoint-web-service.aspx - this one gives error on line - SharePointList.Lists wsList = new SharePointList.Lists();. again I dont know what need to be imported

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sowmyancs/archive/2007/09/15/how-to-download-files-from-a-sharepoint-document-library-remotely-via-lists-asmx-webservice-sps-2003-moss-2007.aspx?PageIndex=2#comments - Gives error at - ListsService.Lists objLists = new SiteDataWebService.ListsService.Lists(); . Again I don't know what needs to be imported

Comment: Are you sure you imported Microsoft.SharePoint.dll?

Comment: Version of sharepoint I use is : 2010

Comment: Again, even the site you have the code from asks: Do you have Microsoft.SharePoint.dll imported in your project? :)

Comment: I have Microsoft.Sharepoint as a reference and add using microsoft.sharepoint clause in the code at the top. Or does that need to be added differently..

Comment: You don't need to import `Microsoft.SharePoint` namespace since you're calling web service. If you're generating proxy with `wsdl.exe`, make sure you remove namespaces in examples (e.g. `Lists wsList = new Lists();`)